# Why python-trml2pdf package isn't available on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, python

I found that python-trml2pdf package is not available on Ubuntu 18.04 distribution. I has been available until Ubuntu 17.10 distribution.
Is there any specific reason ? Will it be available in the future ?

Answer (score 1):

This package is not part of the Ubuntu 18.04 distribution.

However, it can be installed easily with pip, or by downloading from their [pypi webpage](https://pypi.org/project/trml2pdf/).

You can install the package from the PyPI

```
pip install trml2pdf
```

or if you use python3

```
pip3 install trml2pdf
```

If you only want to download the package use

```
pip download trml2pdf
```

If you don't have already pip installed, do it with

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
```

---

The gda_trml2pdf libs and python scripts can also be found in the **libgda-5.0-common** package. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install libgda-5.0-common
```

After installation it can be found in the `/usr/share/libgda-5.0/gda_trml2pdf/`directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was why it was removed. It existed until 17.10.  Which was the reason to remove this package ?